# Ball painting probability

Tags: probability

Consider $N$ balls, each of a distinct color. Say the colors are labeled $C_1 \ldots C_N$.
You choose 2 balls from the $N$ balls.
You paint the first ball's color to the second ball's color. You do this until all $N$ balls are one color. Note that after you choose a pair and paint the first ball, you put both balls back in the pile.

What is the probability that all $N$ balls will end up with color $C_i$?

It is clear that the answer is $\frac{1}{N}$, by symmetry.

Now suppose that the first $m$ balls are the same color. What is the probability that all balls will end up this color. Apparently the answer is $\frac{m}{n}$.

This answer makes sense because it seems it's just summing up the $\frac{1}{N}$ probability $m$ times, and it makes sense that the probability is proportional to the number of balls of that color.

But, at the same time, I don't understand this from a mathematical standpoint. Why is the probability equivalent to summing up the $\frac{1}{N}$ probability $m$ times? This seems to have some sort of mutual exclusivity assumption. Why is this justified?

Are there other intuitive ways to think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Because if you distinguish the identically colored balls with subscripts that become invisible at the end of the process, you'll end up with each subscripted color at the end with probability $\frac 1N$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that that is the approach, but I am confused why this works. If for the first $m$ balls you label their colors as $d_1 \ldots d_m$, and then add up the probability that all the balls are $d_1, \ldots d_m$, it seems you are assuming exclusivity, but underneath we know all $d_1, \ldots, d_m$ are the same color, so the mutually exclusivity seems wrong.

Comment: Exclusivity holds because the painting algorithm works exactly the same way whether you subscript the colors or not.  The algorithm might continue a while longer in the subscripted case, but only to choose which subscript, which doesn't affect the probability of ending up in one of the subscripted colors.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that there are two observers A and B, B is completely color blind and can only read the subscript.

After some repetitions, A notice that all balls have the same color and call it a day. However, B insist that they continue until all the balls have the same subscript. Continuing even after all balls have the same color (not necessarily the same subscript) does not alter the outcome nor the probability of any color remain at the end.

Hope it clarify why it is simpliy $\frac{m}{n}$